# Is there a way to take only the value of a lookup type field

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, lookup-column, designer

I am using a workflow where I need the value of a lookup field,

- My current result is : `210;#AA8888AA`
- It needs to be: `AA8888AA`

Is there a way to take only the value using SharePoint Designer or I need to do the workflow from the Visual Studio?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?  Not all features are available in all SPD versions.

Comment: SPD 2013, I found there is a option to take it only by value. When u are giving the field which  you want to be return, there is a dropdown where you need to choose Lookup Value (as Text) and it will return you only the value :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking around in SPD, I found a solution to the problem.

SharePoint Designer 2013 gives you the option to choose only the value of a lookup field. There is a dropdown menu which asks you what type of data you want to be returned. You need to choose Lookup Value (as Text) and you will take only the value of the lookup field, without id and the additional symbols.

Comment: Really great outcome !!!!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use `Split` action on workflow. Using `Split` action you can split the string. In your case separator should be `;#`.

I found following details from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/749471/string-processing-workflow-actions-for-sharepoint).

[image]

Comment: This way it's working too, but I managed to find a really simple solution, which I have added. Your answer is really helpful and can be used in many situations.